# Copying Cell Value to Clipboard

Tags: vba, excel

I've tried using the below code to copy the cell value to a clipboard and paste it just using the shortcut `Ctrl+V` (not hardcoded, just manual), but it just paste the characters `??`. Anybody knows how to deal with it?

```
temp.Range("BM1").Value = ws.txtFileName

With New DataObject
    .SetText temp.Range("BM1").Text
    .PutInClipboard
End With
```

`txtFileName` is an activeX textbox. Or anyone knows how to copy the textbox value directly to the clipboard?

Comment: If you are using Win8 or later and you have Windows Explorer open, there is a bug that does what you describe. It is safer to use API calls.

Comment: @Rory What do you mean by API?

Comment: Check this here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37843131/excel-vba-dataobjectputinclipboard-not-implemented

Answer (score 0):

API version:

```
Option Explicit
#If Mac Then
    ' ignore
#Else
    #If VBA7 Then
        Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
        Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
        Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalAlloc Lib "kernel32" (ByVal wFlags As Long, _
                                                             ByVal dwBytes As LongPtr) As LongPtr

        Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "User32" () As Long
        Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "User32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr
        Declare PtrSafe Function EmptyClipboard Lib "User32" () As Long

        Declare PtrSafe Function lstrcpy Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpString1 As Any, _
                                                         ByVal lpString2 As Any) As LongPtr

        Declare PtrSafe Function SetClipboardData Lib "User32" (ByVal wFormat _
                                                                As Long, ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    #Else
        Declare Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
        Declare Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
        Declare Function GlobalAlloc Lib "kernel32" (ByVal wFlags As Long, _
                                                     ByVal dwBytes As Long) As Long

        Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "User32" () As Long
        Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "User32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
        Declare Function EmptyClipboard Lib "User32" () As Long

        Declare Function lstrcpy Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpString1 As Any, _
                                                 ByVal lpString2 As Any) As Long

        Declare Function SetClipboardData Lib "User32" (ByVal wFormat _
                                                        As Long, ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
    #End If
#End If
Public Const GHND = &H42
Public Const CF_TEXT = 1
Public Const MAXSIZE = 4096

Function ClipBoard_SetData(MyString As String)
    #If Mac Then
        With New MSForms.DataObject
            .SetText MyString
            .PutInClipboard
        End With
    #Else
        #If VBA7 Then
            Dim hGlobalMemory As LongPtr
            Dim hClipMemory   As LongPtr
            Dim lpGlobalMemory    As LongPtr
        #Else
            Dim hGlobalMemory As Long
            Dim hClipMemory   As Long
            Dim lpGlobalMemory    As Long
        #End If

        Dim x                 As Long

        ' Allocate moveable global memory.
        '-------------------------------------------
        hGlobalMemory = GlobalAlloc(GHND, Len(MyString) + 1)

        ' Lock the block to get a far pointer
        ' to this memory.
        lpGlobalMemory = GlobalLock(hGlobalMemory)

        ' Copy the string to this global memory.
        lpGlobalMemory = lstrcpy(lpGlobalMemory, MyString)

        ' Unlock the memory.
        If GlobalUnlock(hGlobalMemory) <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "Could not unlock memory location. Copy aborted."
            GoTo OutOfHere2
        End If

        ' Open the Clipboard to copy data to.
        If OpenClipboard(0&) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Could not open the Clipboard. Copy aborted."
            Exit Function
        End If

        ' Clear the Clipboard.
        x = EmptyClipboard()

        ' Copy the data to the Clipboard.
        hClipMemory = SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hGlobalMemory)

OutOfHere2:

        If CloseClipboard() = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Could not close Clipboard."
        End If
    #End If

End Function
```

And then your calling code becomes:

```
temp.Range("BM1").Value = ws.txtFileName

    Clipboard_setdata temp.Range("BM1").Text
```

Comment: Is this the same with here: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2015/1/13/how-to-use-vba-code-to-copy-text-to-the-clipboard ?

Comment: @ramedju Roughly, yes, except my version is correctly adapted for 64bit, unlike that one. ;)